# jquery ajax with Servicestack service that include async method call, get return from async method

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asynchronous, servicestack

i have jquery ajax calling servicestack service.
The servicestack service call async method on server side.
Here is the scenario;

my service save the data and return the return object thats ok no problem.

but i need to get response from async method to jquery client

how to do that? pls help...

```
public class MyService : Service
{
    public GenericResponse Any(EditRequest request)
    {
        GenericResponse result = new GenericResponse();

        _repo.Do(request.data, "add");

        result.hasMessage = true;
        result.message.messageType = Enums.MessageTypes.Success;
        result.message.messageData = "save success";

        return result;
    }
}


//_repo methods
public void Do(object data, string oper)
{
    WEBBeanClient client = new WEBBeanClient();
    client.BeginInsert(data, username, password, callback, client);
}

private void callback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    var client = asyncResult.AsyncState as WEBBeanClient;
    var result= client.EndInsert(asyncResult);
    // need to get return here to jquery client
}
```